# 2 in app purchases module in one application in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase, non-renewing-subscription

I have 2 in-app-purchase in my iOS application which is developed using phone gap.
I am using inappPurchaseManager.js for implementing in-app-purchase.

https://github.com/usmart/InAppPurchaseManager-EXAMPLE

1st in app is non-consumable and second one is non-renewing in-app.
in case of restoring the in-app purchase,I used the following code.

```
window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.restoreCompletedTransactions();
window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.onRestored = function(originalTransactionIdentifier, productId, originalTransactionReceipt) {
        console.log("originalTransactionIdentifier: " +  originalTransactionIdentifier);
        console.log("productId: " + productId);
        console.log("originalTransactionReceipt : " + originalTransactionReceipt)

    };
```

but though I have bought 1st and 2nd in-app, This function will only return 1st in-app product name.I don't know that whether I am understanding this code or process wrong.Please give me proper guidelines.I am using apple test account for testing this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behavior, quote from [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW9):

> If your app uses non-renewing subscriptions, your app is responsible for the restoration process.